# How to detect that arrow key is pressed using C under Linux or Solaris?

Tags: c, linux, solaris

What is the best way to detect in a C program that arrow key is pressed under Linux or Solaris?

As I know there is no standard C function that can do it.
I don't want to use int86 function. I need to do it in a portable way.

**Edit**: I am asking about console applications.

Comment: Are you referring to a console application (i.e. no windows)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should look at the curses/ncurses library which will give you advanced screen and keyboard handling for console applications.

There is a lot of [documentation](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) available for curses, which is an extensive library.

There is a write-up on this very question available [here](http://parameshm.blogspot.com/2005/11/how-to-getor-read-arrow-key-input-in-c.html)

Comment: This answer is spot-on. Especially if you want it portable, don't reinvent the wheel, just use a library and spare the headache.

Comment: As pointed out by Francis the original Documentation link is now a 404. Repointed to a new source

Comment: As of 2023, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75499310/6013016) is the solution

Answer (score 2):

I believe your program should switch into [non-canonical mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Terminal-Modes.html#Terminal-Modes) to be able to read special characters

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do this without using something like SDL, you should look into the select() statement and how to use it to read from console input.