# How to listen for arrow key press in C

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to listen for the up and down arrow keys. I have tried using **conio.h** by installing it manually  but it doesn't work either — I am getting an error. I am using Kali Linux.

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <curses.h>
int main() {

int ch = getch();

return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cckPLPKN.o: in function `main': test.c:(.text+0x9):
undefined reference to `getch' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
status
```

Comment: According to [`getch(3)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getch), you need the `<curses.h>` header and `ncurses` library. You should use the `-lncurses` linker option. It is not clear if your used it. Please show your compile and link commands.

Comment: `conio` is specific to older Microsoft systems (DOS and Windows) - it's not appropriate for Linux.  You just need `ncurses`.

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick :

**For Windows:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(){
   int ch;

   printf("Press # to Exit\n");

   while ((ch = getch()) != '#'){
      if (ch == 0 || ch == 224) {
         switch (getch()) {
            case 72:
               printf("\nUp Arrow");
               break;
            case 80:
               printf("\nDown Arrow");
               break;
            case 77:
               printf("\nRight Arrow");
               break;
            case 75:
               printf("\nLeft Arrow");
               break;
         }
      }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

**For Linux:**

```
#include <curses.h>

int main() {
  
    int ch;
    
    /* Curses Initialisations */ 
    initscr();                  /* curses initialization */
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);       /* enable KEY_UP/KEY_DOWN/KEY_RIGHT/KEY_LEFT */
    noecho();                   /* prevent displaying if other keys */
    
    printw("Press # to Exit\n");
 
    while ((ch = getch ()) != '#') {
        switch (ch) {
            case KEY_UP:
                printw ("\nUp Arrow");
                break;
            case KEY_DOWN:
                printw ("\nDown Arrow");
                break;
            case KEY_RIGHT:
                printw ("\nLeft Arrow");
                break;
            case KEY_LEFT:
                printw ("\nRight Arrow");
                break;
        }
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

And you would have:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code to read pressed character in a loop and display their code:

```
/* we use curses library */
#include <curses.h>

int main(void)
{
    /* curses initialization */
    initscr();

    /* enable pressing arrow key to generate KEY_xxx codes */
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);

    /* make getch wait sometime before returning ERR when no key is pressed */
    timeout(100);

    /* do not display pressed key */
    noecho();
    while (1)
    {
        /* read last pressed key */
        int ch = getch();

        /* if no key was waiting, ignore */
        if (ERR == ch)
            continue;

        /* if UP is pressed... */
        if (KEY_UP == ch)
        {
            /* ...do something with that key */
            /* and wait next key pressed */ 
            continue;
        }


        /* if Q is pressed, exit the loop */   
        if ('q' == ch)
            break;

        /* else, display the key code */ 
        mvprintw(2,2,"code get: 0x%x\n", ch);

        /* and some refresh can be useful*/ 
        refresh();
    }

    /* before quitting, disable curses mode */
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

---

Compile with curses library:

```
gcc -Wall main.c -lcurses -ocurses-test
```

That's all.

Comment: the above given code is working as expected, but here is one thing i want to take input from user and at the same time i want to listen for arrow keys, that if the up arrow key is pressed or down just like the linux shell, but when i try to take input in the while loop it is getting messed up.

Comment: How to do the same on windows?